# Splitting text into 2 columns with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to split text into 2 colums. The problem is that then the content of the first class b div becames too much, the div is put under the main div.

html

```
<div class="a textbox">
This is a main div
</div>

<div class="b textbox"> <!-- the problem is when this text became too much, the second class b div is pushed under the main one-->
   This is a side bar div
</div>

<div class="b textbox">
   This is another sidebar div
```

css

```
.a{float:left; width:70%; margin:10px;}
.b{float:left; color:blue; width:20%; margin:10px}
.textbox{text-align:justify;padding:10px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;    background: rgba(113,113,113,0.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;}
```

my fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hbqs6/1/

Expected results:

main div    side div1

main div     side div1

main div     side div2

main div     side div2

Comment: Yeah, those divs always do that. Shame on em.

Comment: Linking to a sandbox is great, but please also post your code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="a textbox">
   <p> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
     <p> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p>      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="b">
<div class="textbox"> <!-- the problem is when this text became too much, the second class b div is pushed under the main one-->
   aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="textbox">
    aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a{float:left; width:70%; margin:10px;}
.b{float:right; color:blue; width:20%; margin:10px}
.textbox{text-align:justify;padding:10px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;    background: rgba(113,113,113,0.5);
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;-moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;margin-bottom:10px}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/hbqs6/5/

Comment: Linking to a sandbox is great, but please also post your code here. A short explaination would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

That is how `float: left` works.

I would suggest either using a two cell table row to separate your columns or just have the columns be in two wrapper divs with `display: inline-block` and set a `max-width` on the first one.

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="a textbox">
   <p> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
       aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
     <p> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
         aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p>      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="b textbox"> <!-- the problem is when this text became too much, the second class b div is pushed under the main one-->
   aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa
</div>

<div class="b d textbox">
    aaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .a{float:left; clear:right;width:70%; margin:10px;}
.b{float:right; clear:right;color:blue; width:20%; margin:10px}
.d{float:right; margin-top: 10px;}
.textbox{
    text-align:justify;
    padding:10px;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;  
    background: rgba(113,113,113,0.5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;
}
```

FIDDLE: http://fiddle.jshell.net/hbqs6/4/

Answer (score 1):

Maths and wrappers are your friends, and so is height:auto; see http://fiddle.jshell.net/hbqs6/6/